# Pascal, Pensee #3 and a counterargument to natural theology

Tags: theology, pascal

Here is the text of Pascal's Pensees No. 3 (in the Krailsheimer translation):

> 'There is change and succession in all things.' 'You are wrong, there is . . .'  'Why, do you not say yourself that the sky and the birds prove God?' - 'No.' - 'Does your religion not say so?' - 'No. For though it is true in a sense for some souls whom God has enlightened in this way, yet it is untrue for the majority.'"

The conclusion seems to be a rejection of a certain argument in natural theology to prove the existence of God.  What might Pascal be referring to in the question in the second sentence -- "You are wrong, there is . . ."?  My first inclination is that the putative interlocutor would insist that the divine is not subject to succession and change.  But Pascal seems to be probing a particular argument for the existence of God, and in such a context it doesn't make sense for the interlocutor to jump ahead to some divine attribute (when the every existence of God is under consideration).  Might Pascal be suggesting that some things are not subject to change and succession?  What might those be?  Laws of logic, mathematics, or physics?  Moral truths?  Platonic forms or essences of some sort?  Some more concrete physical entity that was understood to be static?

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read it, but it seems to me that his writings are his thoughts while reading the first two Greek philosophers: Heraclitus and Parmenides.

These two set the stage for philosophy. They existed nearly in the same period (500+bc) and represented the two sides of philosophical thought.

Heraclitus main concept is that of continuous change "everything flows" is his famous saying.

On the other hand Parmenides considered the world as stable and in unity: all reality is one, change is impossible, and existence is timeless and uniform.

Without going into more details they were both trying to conceive reality but from a totally different perspective. Heraclitus used his senses to conceive reality, while Parmenides said that his senses cannot conceive reality because it's hidden behind them etc.

This "dialog" between them created the concept of "ον" ontology, so they (and especially Parmenides) literally created metaphysics. This concept of "ον" was later "transformed" to God.

So to my understanding, Pascal here has a "conversation" with them, trying to correlate these concepts in his mind.

Comment: Thanks Ioannis.  Pensees is an finished work -- a collection of thoughts by Pascal; so there's no way to know for sure, but I like your suggestion.  The first line definitely has a Heraclitean ring to it, and it makes sense to think that Pascal might have had the opposed perspective of Parmenides in mind.  Thanks again.